# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

WordPress Development's [fifth moderator election](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Jack Johansson]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6094883118907392/0).

Comment: Congrats Jack, welcome to the team! Thank you and Christine for applying to be moderators, it was a [close, close race](https://www.opavote.com/results/6094883118907392/0).

Comment: Thanks everyone for voting. It was actually super super close!

Comment: Congrats! It was a close victory between 2 great candidates

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you! You could say, closest election of WPSE.

Comment: If I knew one vote would have been deciding, I would have actually cast my own vote on myself! :D Congratulations @JackJohansson! See you all on the next elections. <3

Comment: The power of one ;-)  Two great candidates. Congratulations.

Comment: @birgire Thank you so much! It was almost like flipping a coin ;-)

Comment: Congratulations!!

Answer (score 8):

**Thanks** to both of you for volunteering!
Enjoy your new job as a moderator, Jack :)

Answer (score 4):

Congratualtions.

Jack's been very helpful on many ocassions and I've learned a bunch from him.

May his reign bring even more prosperity.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish I'd be more helpful this way.